# Inequality comparison between strings in Oracle

Tags: oracle, comparison, inequality

```
SELECT LAST_NAME FROM Employees
WHERE last_name < 'King';
```

In the book 'SQL Fundamentals I Exam Guide' it says that on the comparison `LAST_NAME < 'King'` occurs the following convertion in the NLS settings assuming a US7ASCII database character set with AMERICAN NLS settings:

```
K + i + n + g = 75 + 105 + 110 + 103 = 393.
```

Then for each row in the table EMPLOYEES table, the LAST_NAME column is similarly converted to  a numeric value. If this value is less than 393, then the row is selected.
But when i execute the SELECT command above, on SQL*PLUS, it returns rows(for example 'Greenberg', 'Bernestein') that does not follow the rule mentioned on the book. Are there any settings that i need to make to obtain rows that satisfy that rule?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule is certainly not valid. If it was, then you could swap the characters and you would still get the same result `393`. But character ordering matters when comparing words.

To get a value appropriate for comparison you would have to calculate like this:

```
K + i + n + g = ((75 × 256 + 105) × 256 + 110) × 256 + 103
```

But you would exceed the valid range of numeric values for long words. For 7-bit ASCII codes (strictly in the range 0 ... 127) you could also multiply with 128 instead of 256.

--

In realty, the values are compared one by one, i.e (in pseudo code):

```
valueOf(last_name[0]) < 75 OR
valueOf(last_name[1]) < 105 OR
valueOf(last_name[2]) < 110 OR
valueOf(last_name[3]) < 103
```

... where the comparisions stop at the first inequality encountered or if the end of one of the words is reached, then the lengths of the words are compared.

In other words, the characters of the 2 words are compared character by character until two different characters are encountered. Then the comparison of these two characters yields the final result.

Take `'Kelvin' < 'King'` as an example:

```
'K' < 'K' ==> false
'e' < 'i' ==> true
final result = true
```

Other example `'King' < 'Kelvin'`  (words are swapped):

```
'K' < 'K' ==> false
'i' < 'e' ==> false, the characters are not equal, therefore stop
final result = false
```

Other example `'be' < 'begin'`:

```
'b' < 'b' ==> false
'e' < 'e' ==> false
end of first word reached, length('be') < length('begin') ==> true
final result = true
```

The actual comparison of two characters is performed by comparing their numeric values, as you have mentioned already.

Answer (score 4):

If that is actually what the book says, the book is wildly and frighteningly incorrect.  If we're talking about the Oracle Press book, I would strongly suspect that you're misreading the explanation because I am hard-pressed to imagine how that mistake could make it through without getting caught by the author, the editor, or a reviewer.

To compare two strings, you do exactly the same thing that you do when you're putting strings in alphabetical order by hand.  The string "B" comes after the string "All My Data" and before the string "Changes Constantly".  You take the first character of the string and look at the decimal representation ('A' is 65, 'B' is 66, and 'C' is 67) and order based on that.  If there are ties, say "All Data" and "All Indexes", you move on to the second character and compare until you can break the tie 'D' is 68 which is less than 'I' which is 73 so "All Data" < "All Indexes".

Comment: I understood your explanation but i still think the book follow another rule to solve that inequality, if you want to read here is what the book says http://i.imgur.com/KqfCczS.png?1

Comment: @RoniCastro - The approach the book suggests is fundamentally, totally, completely, absolutely incorrect.

Comment: I can't even imagine how did they manage to actually write that AND pass all QC in a book that's **preparing you for taking an exam**, no less. Perhaps they misinterpreted `In binary comparison, which is the default, Oracle compares character strings according to the concatenated value of the numeric codes of the characters in the database character set.` from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements002.htm)? It's still an atrocious misconception which says a lot about book's authors actual experience.